# Sybase SQL - Distinct over union clause

Tags: sql, distinct, union, sybase

I have a code here that was from a colleague that left my firm and I'm trying to run it faster. Basically, it does the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    column1,
    ISNULL(column2,0),
    column3
FROM (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN ...
    WHERE ...

    UNION

    SELECT ALL column1, column2, column3
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN ...
    WHERE ...

) as DT
```

I was checking some sites and found that the UNION clause only gets distincts values. With the distinct clause it takes like 15 sec to execute and without, 3 sec. (The query is a bit complex :/).
So in any case would the DISTINCT on the first query make any difference or I could simply remove it?

Thanks in advance!

---

--- edit for who may find this useful :) ---
the problem was on the ISNULL that was used after the UNION statement. After I changed it to be inside the sub-query the performance was the same as removing the distinct.

Comment: You might find that the distinct keyword improves performance.  Have you done any testing?

Comment: I did some tests, and using this DISTINCT in the beginning is making the whole query executes in 15sec. Without it, it takes only 3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it if you do not have a null value in your table. They are semantically equivalent in that case. But not so if there are null values as having `Distinct` adds null values and so does `SELECT ALL`.

Comment: Just one thing I realized.. on the second query, there is a "SELECT ALL" (I edited just now the query in the question). But still, I think it doesn't change, right?

Comment: Hmm I was intrigued when you said it shouldn't affect the performance and found what is the problem. On the first select, it has a ISNULL condition, so I assume this is the problem, as it "changes" the value after the union. I included the ISNULL condition in the inner query and left the distinct just in case, but now it takes only 3 sec again. Thank you for your help!